# flush opera DNS cache

Tags: dns, cache, opera

for a developer that has to update DNS entries to do testing and other tasks, how do you clear the DNS cache in Opera.

Or lower the extremely long cache that get's in your way after editing `/etc/hosts` file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to Opera's Senior Developer, Yngve Nysæter Pettersen](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/findpost.pl?id=3961301), the DNS cache in Opera is **10 minutes** and there's no means (that he cares to share) to clear it.

That's extremely inconvenient. And my trial and error shows that closing and opening the browser (whole browser, not just tab) successfully cleared the cache immediately.

He's wrong when he says that this is the same on every other browser. This may be true in Chrome as they rip settings every day, but Firefox has `network.dnsCacheExpiration` with is miliseconds for DNS cache TTL. (This is not documented or shown with the default value when you go to `about:config`, but still existent.)

Comment: btw, firefox and chrome now are exactly the same. Firefox used to allow dns ttl to be set via a non-documented user setting. but since i keep losing my notes, i have no idea which one it was... and i'm too lazy to scour the source code again. I just delete my profile and create a new one... sigh.

Comment: In Chrome you can clear dns cache by opening the following url `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and click on the "clear host cache" button. So no need for deleting you profile.

Comment: This works also with Opera (version 33.0): `browser://net-internals/#dns`

Comment: Actually, in Opera 64.0, is: `opera://net-internals/#dns`

Answer (score 8):

[@GeorgDangl](https://superuser.com/users/438843/georgdangl) gives the answer

```
browser://net-internals/#dns
```